# CSS print multiple A4 pages will cause extra blank pages

Tags: html, css, printing

I've read so many articles about printing with CSS rules, but I still have the same problem as always.

My application will look like Google Docs in a very simple way. What I want is multiple A4 pages in my view and when I hit 'print', I want to see the same A4 pages for printing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pages</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sheet"></div>
    <div class="sheet"></div>
    <div class="sheet"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is all my CSS:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@media screen {
  body {
    background: #f8f9fa;
  }
}

@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 0;
}

.sheet {
  width: 8.27in;
  height: 11.69in;
  padding: 1.5cm;
}

@media screen {
  .sheet {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15);
  }
}

@media print {
  .sheet {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

But now I got **3 pages**. The second one is empty.

I can choose to use the width and height only in 'screen' mode, but what if I want to use `position: relative` on a page with some `position: absolute`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? `page-break-after: always;` is why you're getting 3 pages instead of 2. [Look up what `page-break-after` does.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/#page-break-after) Hint: It adds another page after the break.

Comment: I have a `<div>` as big as A4. Then I add a `page-break-after: always;`, so the next `<div>` will be on a new page. But it looks like my `width` and `height` are slightly higher than Chrome print function thinks, so it is already on a new page and then it will add a `page-break`.

Can you suggest a better way then?